# The criteria of commuting two formal power series,

Tags: formal-power-series

Let $f = x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $g = x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ be two formal series without constant term. Then
$$
f \circ g(x) =x+ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n (x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k)^n, 
$$ Similarly, $$
g \circ f(x) =x+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k (x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n)^k.
$$
Now, we have
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k x^k \right)^n = \sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k} x^n, \ i_k \geq 1.
$$
I want to get the conditions when $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ i.e., when the two power series commutes each other. Then, $$x+ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n (x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k)^n=x+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k (x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n)^k,$$ 
i.e., $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n (x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k)^n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k (x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n)^k$$,
i.e, $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\cdots+\color{blue}{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n (\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}b_kx^k)^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k x^k+\cdots+\color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} b_k(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n)^k}. $$
The first two terms of both sides cancels out and  comparing the last term of both sides i.e, coefficients of $x^{kn}$, we get
$$
a_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k}\right) = b_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} a_{i_1} \dotsm a_{i_k}\right),\ i_k \geq 2.
$$ But how to deal with middle $\cdots$ terms  ??

That is, what is criteria so that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$. ?

Comment: Your lower summation index should be $2$ instead of $1$ since you already have $x$ by itself.

Comment: @Somos, oh, yes,thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question "But how to deal with middle ... terms??" What are you trying to do here? Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: @Somos, I want to find the criteria when $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$. I arranged the equality but having problem to compare the coefficients of $x$ from both sides. As you in the last equation,I compared the coefficient of $x^{kn}$. What about the other coefficients so that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$  ?

Comment: When you equate the terms of $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ you get, for example, the coefficient of $x^4$ giving $a_2^2b_2+a_2b_3=b_2^2a_2+b_2a_3$. You get similar equations for the higher coefficients.

Comment: @Somos, so I am searching the general form. I think if you put $n=3$ in my above last formula, it will be your result. In that case the last equation is the general result

Comment: I think you may want to use Faa di Bruno's formula for composition of exponential generating functions using the exponential Bell polynomials.

Comment: @Somos,no,it is simple that what I am asking.I am asking if $f \circ g=g \circ f$, then what is the $\text{relations among the coefficients}$ as you did for $x^4$. That is what I am asking for general term or for $x^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why you got stuck.

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n (\sum_{m\ge 1} b_m x^m)^n=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n \sum_{r \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^n} \prod_{j=1}^n b_{r_j} x^{r_j} = \sum_{l\ge 1} x^l \sum_{n=1}^l a_n \sum_{r \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^n, \sum_{j=1}^n r_j = l}\prod_{j=1}^n b_{r_j} $$
and $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n (\sum_{m\ge 1} b_m x^m)^n=\sum_{n\ge 1} b_n (\sum_{m\ge 1} a_m x^m)^n$ iff $$\sum_{n=1}^l a_n \sum_{r \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^n, \sum_{j=1}^n r_j = l}\prod_{j=1}^n b_{r_j}=\sum_{n=1}^l b_n \sum_{r \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^n, \sum_{j=1}^n r_j = l}\prod_{j=1}^n a_{r_j}$$

Comment: Thanks. But I think the indices will  start from $n=2$ instead of $n=1$.

Comment: No, $a_1=1$, there is no reason to separate $x^1$

Comment: ok, It is clear now